# How to show Additional charge on COD in invoice pdf magento 2?

Tags: payment-methods, invoice, pdf, magento-2.1.8, cash-on-delivery

I am using an extension to add additional fee on Cash on Delivery payment gateway.

It is working fine but the COD fee is not showing in invoice pdf.

This issue only for the admin invoice pdf.

How can I add this information in pdf?

Comment: check the full explanation, https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/display-extra-fee-to-invoice-pdf-magento/

Answer (score 1):

create pdf.xml file under etc folder

add add below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Sales:etc/pdf_file.xsd">
  <totals>
    <total name="cgst">
      <title translate="true">Cgst</title>
      <source_field>cgst_charge</source_field>
      <display_zero>false</display_zero>
      <sort_order>550</sort_order>
    </total>
</config>
```

change code as per your need

Comment: Not working, I have added pdf.xml in the module. But the COD fee is not showing.

Comment: there is a column of codcharge is you invoice table or not??

Comment: its working for me in my GST extension

Comment: In my case, COD charge is 'cash_on_delivery_fee' in the table

Comment: does you add any field in Invoice table or not???

Comment: No, field in sales_order table

Comment: than you need to create field in invoice table to get detail in pdf

Comment: 'cash on delivery charge' is not showing only on admin invoice pdf. It is showing everywhere except admin invoice pdf.

Comment: pdf refere to invoice table thats why we need to create column in invoice table, you can create field manually and set some value in any invoice than genarate pdf

Comment: http://prntscr.com/itpbzg

Comment: But, how it is showing in frontend invoice pdf?

Comment: How user Get Pdf In frontend site???

Comment: from My account section.

Answer (score 0):

You are required to create model: Name_space/module_name/Model/Sales/Pdf/Customfee.php

```
    <?php
namespace Name_space\module_name\Model\Sales\Pdf;

class Customfee extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Total\DefaultTotal
{
    public function getTotalsForDisplay()
    {
        $order =  $this->getOrder();
       $amount = $order->getCash_on_delivery_fee(); // 'Cash_on_delivery_fee' replace with your custom attribute 

        $title = __($this->getTitle());
        if ($this->getTitleSourceField()) {
            $label = $title . ' (' . $this->getTitleDescription() . '):';
        } else {
            $label = $title . ':';
        }

        $fontSize = $this->getFontSize() ? $this->getFontSize() : 7;
        $total = ['amount' => '₹'.number_format($amount,2), 'label' => 'Cash on Delivery Charges', 'font_size' => $fontSize];
        return [$total];
    }
}
```